# What is the key derivation function used in GnuPG, and how long may its input be?

Tags: key-derivation, pgp

I am currently working with GnuPG on a new project of mine. It would be very useful to know two things for that, which are not described in the manual:

1. What is the maximum input size of a symmetric key in GnuPG?
2. What key derivation function does GnuPG use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the maximum input size of a symmetric key for GnuPG?

The key size of the symmetric key is defined by the cipher and is derived from a passphrase using OpenPGP's string to key function. The standard does not define a maximum input length, and I'm not aware of a limitation in GnuPG (but did not look up in the source code). Be aware that providing a passphrase as input to the string to key function longer than the symmetric key (ie., having more entropy than the symmetric key) does not increase security any more.

> What key derivation function does GnuPG use?

OpenPGP calls the key derivation function "string to key function", which is defined in [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, String-to-Key (S2K) Specifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7). It boils down to applying a hash function on the passphrase and optionally a salt, usually those get concatenated for a number of iterations to increase the workload for brute force attacks.

Comment: You mean  "...providing a passphrase  **entropy** as input to the string..."  And password entropy is almost impossible to measure if you take a holistic approach.  It could very well be true that longer passwords are more secure even if  their actual byte length >> key size.

Comment: Richard was asking very generally for "maximum input size", which sounds more like a long, random string. But for sure, you're right that my statement is only valid for random input using the whole space of possible passphrases.

Comment: "Be aware that providing a passphrase as input to the string to key function longer than the symmetric key does not increase security any more." This is not true; using a higher entropy password than the security of the key doesn't make sense. But hardly anyone will use passwords that contain 128 bits of entropy or more.