# What happens if you use a password longer then the hash of the KDF?

Tags: encryption, aes, pgp

What happens if you use a password longer then the hash of the KDF? 
For example in GPG symmetric a password which is 200 characters . 
On AES-256 ( I don't know the maximum length of the KDF output).

Comment: Could you at least run a spellcheck on your questions? The quality of your questions is deteriorating quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash functions used as key derivation function take input of arbitrary length (the passphrase) and calculate a fixed-length hash sum used as cipher block (which is 256 bit for AES256, thus the name). Theoretically, you can provide any input size.

$\mathrm{hashfunction}(input) = cipherblock$, while input can have arbitrary length and the hashfunction always returns a 256 bit value.

What [sizes actually are *reasonable* was already discussed in your last question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48952/5122).

Comment: does it have any negative effects ?

Comment: Very long passphrases have some minor impact on calculation times of the hashsum function (but this is likely to be negligible if you're not debating high-traffic servers), and you might hit unexpected issues when exceeding the passphrase length tested by the software implementations you're relying on.